# How to run content migrations when running tests

Tags: craft4

I added a content migration for my custom Craft module. When running tests, I want the migration to be applied as well (otherwise tests will fail).

Therefore I added a `migrations` directory to the `tests/_craft` directory as suggested in the documentation. I copies my migration class file into the migrations directory.

Then I added the migration class to my `codeception.yml`

```
modules:
    config:
        \craft\test\Craft:
            configFile: "tests/_craft/config/test.php"
            entryUrl: "https://famrat-craft.dev.test/index.php"
            projectConfig:  {folder: '../../config/project', reset: false}
            migrations: [
                {class: 'craft\contentmigrations\m240115_093100_update_module_table', params: {}}
            ]
            plugins: []
            cleanup: true
            transaction: true
            dbSetup: { clean: true, setupCraft: true }
```

Nonetheless I always get the error

```
Migration class: craft\contentmigrations\m240115_093100_update_module_table does not exist
```

There is very little to find on the internet about this topic.
I tried different things to make it work but did not succeed.

Any help is greatly appreciated!